# Elasticsearch Java API Boost query with Match Phrase (Exact Search) Clause

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

My end goal is to perform exact search on a phrase entered (Example: Test Type Search) and boosting the result if say the exact phrase matches to the column that I am looking for.

I am using the the Elasticsearch Java APIs for this.
Please find the code as below,

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("_all", "Test Type Search");

SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("index_name")
                        .setQuery(queryBuilder)
                        .setFrom(1)
                        .setSize(10)
                        .execute()
                        .actionGet();
```

I would like to know how to boost a field in the index that contains this exact value.

The above response also returns responses that has values say, "Test code is used for this Type of Search" and not exactly "Test Type Search". How can I rectify this?

Is there a way I can find proper Elasticsearch Java API documentation (2.0.0)?

Comment: have you find a solution? thanks

Answer (score 0):

From your question it looks like you want to match whole term(value) only i.e. "Test Type Search".

For this you can use **QueryBuilders.termQuery(field, value)**
and for matching terms, 
use **QueryBuilders.matchQuery(field, value)**
wherein 
field : your doc field on which you want to query
value : what exactly you want to match.

Refer ES [Doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/index.html)
Refer ES Java API [Doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html)